# Self-updating field containing a substring of the filename, how-to?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I have documents with filenames like:

- "111-222-333 this is the manual.docx"
- "111-222-444 this is another doc.docx"

Inside the doc, there is a reference field displaying the 11 leftmost characters of the filename (e.g. `Ref : 111-222-333`, `Ref : 111-222-444`).

Is there a way, in word 2010, to use an object that would auto-update when I change the filename?

I have not found a way to do something like `{LEFT(filename, 11)}` and was wondering if somebody had a clever idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late to the party here, but this might work for you if there is still a need and all your files follow the example pattern you gave.

1. Insert a filename field: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> and within the resulting braces
   type `FILENAME \*MERGEFORMAT`
2. Update the field by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>
3. Format everything after the last number as hidden: highlight the text, right click, Font, check Hidden

File names do not auto-update as might be expected, so there is a manual step to update as your document changes its file name. You can select all text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and update all fields (<kbd>F9</kbd>) or assign a macro to a button on your quick access toolbar that runs this macro and click the button instead:

```
Sub UpdateAllFields()
    ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
End Sub
```

There are also macro actions that can be set to update all fields on document open, but you may not want to do that for globally.

Comment: Brilliant! I doubted it was even possible but you nailed it!

Comment: Thanks! Glad it worked for you--I am happy I spent the time on older questions.